# Using decorator on a variable in a function in Python

Tags: python, variables, decorator

I would like to use a decorator for validating data in Python.
Normally in Python one uses a decorator on a function, but I would like to use a decorator on a variable, similar to Java:

```java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      @BoldWrapper
      @ItalicWrapper
      String str = "Hello World";
      // Display <b><i>Hello World</i></b>
   }
}

public @interface BoldWrapper {
    public void wrap() default "<b>" + str + "</b>";
}

public @interface ItalicWrapper {
    public void wrap() default "<i>" + str + "</i>";
}
```

So in Python I would have something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    @BoldWrapper
    @ItalicWrapper
    str = "Hello World";
```

Comment: You can only decorate functions/methods and classes

Comment: You can decorate a function and have it return that string.

Comment: @fechnert - you can decorate getters/setters which would, from the outside, appear as properties.

Comment: @zwer - which are functions in the first place ;) but yeah, thats also a possible way

Comment: Java annotations != Python decorators... see [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3j5aqw/java_annotations_what_are_they/)

Comment: Thank you @zwer for the link!

Answer (score 1):

only classes and functions/methods definitions may be decorated (functions/methods since **Python 2.4**, classes since **Python 2.6**):

from docs about [function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function)

> A function definition may be wrapped by one or more decorator expressions. Decorator expressions are evaluated when the function is defined, in the scope that contains the function definition.

and [class definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions)

> Classes can also be decorated: just like when decorating functions

so

```
@BoldWrapper
@ItalicWrapper
text = "Hello World"
```

will cause [`SynaxError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError).

There is no need for this feature, because we can just write function calls

```
text = BoldWrapper(ItalicWrapper("Hello World"))
```

### P. S.

- do not use names of built-ins like `str` for your objects,
- semicolons are redundant in **Python**

## Further reading

- functions and methods decorators: [PEP-318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/),
- class decorators: [PEP-3129](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/),
- [**PythonWiki** page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)

Comment: But use `lower_case` because they are functions and not classes

Comment: @fechnert: they may be callable classes, we don't know what is OP's case

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but I would really like to know whether in Python is possible to have a decorator on a variable, not alternatives.

Comment: @Petronella: i answered that it is impossible because there is no need for that

Comment: @Petronella no, it is a syntax error. The decorator syntax is syntactic sugar for `f = deco(f)` after a function definition. It merely exists for the added benefit of readability - one often wants to see the decorators before reading the function body. Decorators in Python are not the same thing as annotations in Java.